# Markers issue when uploading KML file my website using API key

Tags: javascript

everyone, I have uploaded my google map KML file to my website then I have used google map javascript API key. if you notice once you run the map you will see all my markers in white( transparent ) is there a way to have my map exactly the same way like I had it before saving. the code below, Thank you in advance:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.5715, -97.66704),
        });
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'https://rogerslimos.com/KML.kml',
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```